# How does the MethodImplAttribute work in .NET?

Tags: .net, attributes, disassembly

I was investigating some framework code (the System.AppDomain.GetDynamicDir method) and this was all the assembler showed:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private extern string GetDynamicDir();
```

What happens when this method is called? I don't mean this specific method, but methods with this attribute in general.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx):

> **MethodImplOptions.InternalCall**: Specifies an internal
>   call. An internal call is a call to a
>   method that is implemented within the
>   common language runtime itself.

So basically, the CLR provides its own implementation of this method (which is probably in native code), which is why you can't see it in the disassembler.

Comment: I found the methods here: http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid006DC4C11F458707221DA6ED2ED9CC3C7AE12E11.aspx

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163896.aspx) :

> (...)
>   **`MethodImplOptions.InternalCall`** is used
>   in conjunction with extern to tell the
>   runtime that the method is implemented
>   internally within the system itself.
>   This is done for many of the core .NET
>   Framework methods that are better
>   served by being implemented in
>   unmanaged code. For example, many of
>   the methods on the **`String`**, **`GC`**, and
>   Math classes are marked as
>   **`InternalCall`**. As you've noticed,
>   **`Guid.CompleteGuid`** is also an
>   **`InternalCall`**.