# How to find sources of .Net external method

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods

I am looking at [HasFlag](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,9cd73f33d2df3074) implementation, there is `InternalHasFlag(...)` call. How can I see sources of it?

Question tittle might be a bit misleading (feel free to correct).

My original problem comes from attempt to make `enum` extension method, here is one

```
public static Enum Mask(this Enum @this, Enum mask)
{
    if (mask == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("mask");
    if (!@this.GetType().IsEquivalentTo(mask.GetType()))
        throw new ArgumentException("Type mismatch", "mask");
    return (Enum)(object)((int)(object)@this & (int)(object)mask);
}
```

I am very unsure in last line and wanted to see how ms-guy does it.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011702/how-does-the-methodimplattribute-work-in-net), as it's applied to the `InternalHasFlag` method - ie it's an implementation detail of the CLR.  You may be able to find more over on the [recent open source releases](https://github.com/dotnet/core)

Comment: The source cod of .NET is available [online](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/). [InternalHasFlag](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,7a5a597a638c2fdf) though isn't a .NET method, it's part of the runtime itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The OP links HasFlag in the reference source and is specifically asking how to find out how `InternalHasFlag` works because it isn't visible there (to my reading of the question at least).

Comment: Asking for external resources, such as .NET Framework or CLR source code if off-topic for Stack Overflow. Is your underlying question _"Is this implementation correct?"_? See [Reimplementing Enum.HasFlag for use in Mono 2.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278588/reimplementing-enum-hasflag-for-use-in-mono-2-6), [.NET's Enum.HasFlag and performance costs](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/441086/NETs-Enum-HasFlag-and-performance-costs).

Comment: @CodeCaster, if you want to get sources of *external* method (*internal* for .net?), then how you do it? Perhaps by disassembling? I am not asking for link (thus not an offtopic I think), nor I am trying to re-implement `HasFlag` or having problem with it. I just posted original problem, because maybe someone can give me answer right away and I don't need `InternalHasFlag` sources anymore.

Comment: Read your question. _"I am very unsure in last line"_ is not a proper problem description. Remove the parts about the .NET CLR source code (which _is_ off-topic - and the CLR is written in C++ and hard to decompile, you could take a look at Mono and see how they do it) and ask a proper question about how to implement your Mask method.

Comment: @CodeCaster, thanks for [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/441086/NETs-Enum-HasFlag-and-performance-costs) link, this should be the answer tbh. They use `ulong` (and I was using `int`) as well as some methods instead of casting.

Comment: FWIW, I think [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/reflectioninvocation.cpp#L3707) is the implementation.  As you can see, it's no longer .NET as it's part of the CLR that's running your .NET code.  I found it using [a simple google search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:github.com+internalhasflag&filter=0)

Comment: @JamesThorpe, thanks. Haven't thought to use google to look for that, lol. But if I would, my question would be different, because I've no idea what is going on in that `FCIMPL2` =)

Comment: I'm struggling to see the point of your extension method. What ultimately are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @StephenKennedy, bits [masking](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10493411/1997232).